# Error while defining XPathSelectElement c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a complex XML file where I want to retrieve different values from the different Set tag.At the end, i need to take the values to a CSV file.

Please see the [xml file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4sMO.jpg)

I am trying to retrieve the value of

```
<szItemID>3268750004533</szItemID> from the first set 
<lMerchandiseStructureID>40</lMerchandiseStructureID> from the second set 
 <szDesc>PHG VIANDE SECHEE DE</szDesc>  from the third set 
 <dPackingUnitPriceAmount>75</dPackingUnitPriceAmount> from the fourth tag
```

I have tried to retrieve the first element through the below code but getting an error

> NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Code

```
 XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(@"D:\\xml_1.xml");

        string myXmlString = document.OuterXml.ToString();

        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(myXmlString);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}",xml.XPathSelectElement("/UpdateDB/Transaction/Insert/Set/szItemID").Value));
```

Please help

```
  StringBuilder dataToBeWritten = new StringBuilder();


        var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\xml_2.xml");

        foreach (var trans in doc.Descendants("Transaction"))

        {
            var val3 = (string)doc.Descendants("Set").Elements("szItemID").First();
            var val4 = (string)doc.Descendants("Set").Elements("lMerchandiseStructureID").First();
            var val5 = (string)doc.Descendants("Set").Elements("szName").First();
            var val6 = (string)doc.Descendants("Set").Elements("lRetailStoreID").First();
            var val7 = (string)doc.Descendants("Set").Elements("bIsContract").First();

            dataToBeWritten.Append(val3);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
            dataToBeWritten.Append(val4);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
            dataToBeWritten.Append(val5);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
            dataToBeWritten.Append(val6);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
            dataToBeWritten.Append(val7);
            dataToBeWritten.Append(",");
            dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        }


        Console.WriteLine(dataToBeWritten.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();


        var testpath = @"D:\\Lutchmee2.csv";

        File.WriteAllText(testpath, dataToBeWritten.ToString());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `XElement` *is* `UpdateDB`, so from that context there is no child `UpdateDB`. You'd have to amend your query to:

```
/Transaction/Insert/Set/szItemID
```

That said, it's unclear why you're loading the document into the DOM, converting it to a string and than parsing to an `XElement`. Just load into an `XDocument` and use your original query:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\xml_1.xml");
var val = (string) doc.XPathSelectElement("/UpdateDB/Transaction/Insert/Set/szItemID");
```

Or better still, use LINQ to XML as it was intended:

```
var val = (string) doc.Descendants("Set").Elements("szItemID").First()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply..This works but i have another issue.. actually if i have an xml file with different transaction tags how do i retrieve each element from each transaction tag ?? Normally the example provided consist of information of one product, i may have file where i have two products..this i have different set of transaction tag.. Note the number of nodes within each transaction will stays the same

Comment: @LBoodia `foreach (var trans in doc.Descendants("Transaction")) { .. }`?

Comment: i have tried the above new code, but all my record are same even though i have different transaction tag with different values..any idea? Thanks so much

Comment: @LBoodia you're not using the `trans` in your loop, you're using `doc`, so you will always get the same result. Use `trans.Descendants(...)` instead.

Comment: what if i need to obtain the second value of the same element tag through the same transaction

Comment: @LBoodia then instead of `First()` you'd call something like `Skip(1).First()`.

Comment: How can i skip the next transaction tag?

Comment: If the transaction set does not contain one mentioned element, i get an error that sequence contains no element. Is there a way i can validate if the element tag are present or not ? if it is not present to escape the transaction set  and proceed with other transaction set?

Comment: @Lutch if you use `FirstOrDefault` (instead of `First`), the expression will return `null` in the case there is no element rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: how can i skip the transaction set incase the element is not present ? If my file contains 50 well structured transaction set and in one transaction set an element is missing i get an error and the whole file is not process. I cannot use null because if the whole row in the csv file has null values the file is not process